# Further Solving for Orthogonal Projections in subspace gives incorrect result

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection, orthogonal-matrices

I was studying Orthogonal Projections on multidimensional subspaces. I checked out the derivation for finding the vectors of the orthogonal projection on the subspace from [here](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/NfYmDxtEEeiDkQoaxapXkA_362ff9c01b4411e8af00d38a13203424_projections.pdf?Expires=1599091200&Signature=XqtHrbVjWqyZ%7E1pSq4ec5WGDShNwGaYkt1BzhDYjdseSMwXKjkkptRPxjOGfrta9aOeC2QDqOzq38qOlIs89WdFAoMmAlgwHmmrxrcgPm8VrsljQtinbcjhsJMJCzUf7mbTkGReZp1HoJnWuyPXSGhwhTNvk2uLG0ecaJTP9ztA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A).

In the given pdf, the equation $(9)$ is

$$B^T(x-B\lambda) = 0$$

which is essentially the inner product of $B$ and $x-B\lambda$ i.e.

$$<B, x-B\lambda> = 0$$

it later solved to

$$\lambda = (B^T B)^{-1}B^Tx$$

All well and good.

But if we proceed a bit further than the pdf to solving the inverse part in this equation, we have

$$\lambda = B^{-1}(B^T)^{-1}B^Tx$$

Here we have $(B^T)^{-1}B^T$, which is as we know is an identity matrix, $I$. So we now have...

$$\lambda = B^{-1}x$$

But if we use this value of $\lambda$ in later equations for projection we get the incorrect result in which projection of $x$ is $x$ itself, which is not possible for all values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So my question is why does doing this simple thing of solving the inverse give an incorrect result? I really hope that I have not done any blunder in solving this simple inverse equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your further step is not valid unless $B$ is an invertible square matrix.

Comment: @hardmath Is it something like we cannot divide a number by 0?

Comment: That is part of it, but note that $B \in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ where $n$ is strictly greater than $m$ (unless the "subspace" $U$ is really all of $\mathbb R^n$).  So $B$ is not a square matrix when the "subspace" is a proper subspace.  And then it makes no sense to write $B^{-1}$.

Comment: @hardmath aaaahhhh...now I get it. Could you give it in the answer, so that I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would only be able to carry out the "further solving" if $B$ were a square (invertible) matrix.  But that case is where the subspace $U$ is indeed all of $\mathbb R^n$.

If $U$ were the entire $n$-dimensional space, then the projection of $x$ on $U$ would be exactly $x$, i.e. $x - B\lambda = 0$.  This is the "trivial" case.

The roundabout construction of $(B^T B)^{-1}$ (the inverse of a nonsingular $m\times m$ matrix) is just what one needs to minimize the "error of approximation" of $x$ by $B\lambda$.  The construction $(B^T B)^{-1} B^T$ is otherwise referred to as the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of a full rank nonsquare matrix $B$.